# Query between 2 tables

Tags: database

I want the date for the last login for a defined role, but I have a problem with my query with drupal 7.

I have the good answer in phpmyadmin with this query :

```
SELECT login FROM `users` AS u, `users_roles` AS r
WHERE u.uid = r.uid
AND r.rid = 3
ORDER BY login DESC LIMIT 1
```

But an error with Drupal7... I tried this code :s :

```
$query = db_select('users','u')
 ->join('users_roles','r','r.uid = u.uid')
 ->fields('u',array('uid'))
 ->fields('r',array('rid'))
 ->condition('r.rid', '3', '=')
 ->orderBy('login', 'DESC')
 ->range(0,1);
$res = $query->execute();
```

Thanks

Edit : Thank for your answer Clive , this code works :

```
$query = db_select('users','u');
$query->join('users_roles','r','r.uid = u.uid');
$query->fields('u',array('login'))
 ->condition('r.rid', '3', '=')
 ->orderBy('login', 'ASC')
 ->range(0,1);

$res = $query->execute();      
return $res->fetchField();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SelectQuery::join()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3Ajoin/7) returns the alias created, not the query object, so it can't be chained. This should work

```
$query = db_select('users','u')
 ->fields('u',array('uid'))
 ->fields('r',array('rid'))
 ->condition('r.rid', '3', '=')
 ->orderBy('login', 'DESC')
 ->range(0,1);

$query->join('users_roles','r','r.uid = u.uid');
$res = $query->execute();
```