# Extend db query in CKEditor Link User module

Tags: database

The [CKEditor Link User module](https://drupal.org/project/ckeditor_link_user) has essentially the functionality I need, but it requires editors to know users by their 'name' field in the users table.  I wanted to extend the query to join with the field_data_field_full_name table so that editors could type full names to populate suggestions.  The original code:

```
<?php

/**
 * Implementation of hook_ckeditor_link_TYPE_autocomplete().
 */
function ckeditor_link_user_ckeditor_link_user_autocomplete($string) {
  $matches = array();

  $result = db_select('users')
    ->fields('users', array('uid', 'name'))
    ->condition('name', '%'. db_like($string) .'%', 'LIKE')
    ->range(0, 10)
    // ->addTag('user_access'); // Make a proper access hook
    ->execute();

  foreach ($result as $user) {
    $matches['user/'. $user->uid] = t('User: @name', array('@name' => $user->name));
  }

  return $matches;
}

...
```

My attempt (edited after SO thoughtfully pointed me [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/95273/query-between-2-tables?rq=1)):

```
<?php

/**
 * Implementation of hook_ckeditor_link_TYPE_autocomplete().
 */
function ckeditor_link_user_ckeditor_link_user_autocomplete($string) {
  $matches = array();

  $result = db_select('users', 'u')
  $result->join('field_data_field_full_name', 'ft', 'ft.entity_id = u.uid')
    ->fields('u', array('uid'))
    ->fields('ft', array('field_full_name_value'))
    ->condition('field_full_name_value', '%'. db_like($string) .'%', 'LIKE')
    ->range(0, 10)
    // ->addTag('user_access'); // Make a proper access hook
    ->execute();

  foreach ($result as $user) {
    $matches['user/'. $user->uid] = t('User: @name', array('@name' => $user->field_full_name_value));
  }

  return $matches;
}

...
```

In the CKEditor Link pop-up, I get a "An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 500 Debugging information follows. Path: /ckeditor_link/autocomplete StatusText: Internal Server Error..." Nothing is showing up in the error log.  I have set Devel to show SQL queries, but I don't see the Ajax query from autocomplete anywhere.